# How can I code a text strikethrough, specifically for the past description text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, momentjs

I'm working on a scheduler and wanted to know how would I add a strikethough/crossout the text of something from the past? I hope this question makes sense.

```
function background () {
    var currentHour = moment().hours();
    $(".time-block").each(function () {
        var divTimeId = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
        // Past
        if (divTimeId < currentHour) {
            $(this).addClass("past");

            // Present
        } else if (divTimeId === currentHour) {
            $(this).removeClass("past");
            $(this).removeClass("future");
            $(this).addClass("present");
            // Future
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("past");
            $(this).removeClass("present");
            $(this).addClass("future");
        }
    })
 }
//  Background
 background ();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I have to make an entirely new function for that since I'm targeting the background specifically to change colors based on the time, or if I can add it to the function

Comment: if I understand correct, adding "text-decoration: line-through;" to the past class in the css should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes it worked thank you, it's unfornately also striking through all the times though since they're in the "past" too

Comment: *"How can I add strikethrough to past items?"* ... "do x" .. *"but that adds strikethough to past items"*.

Comment: Add a (new) class to the ones you want to strikethrough and style that class.